# javascript - highchart xaxis datetime and yaxis data

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, highcharts

I have below a series:

```
[{"name":"date","data":455661712000,1455661791000,1455661869000,1455661947000,1455662568000,1455662646000]},
{"name":"numues","data":[14,13,14,12,12,12]},
{"name":"rpcnt","data":[4,4,4,4,4,4]}]
```

In `Highchart` options, values are set as using below code.

```
options9.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
options9.series[0] = json[1];
options9.series[1] = json[2];
options9.series[2] = json[3];`
```

But my graph does not plot x axis as time. It consider each as string (just point) instead of value. (the gap between 2 values random.)

How plot x-axis as datetime?

Comment: Could you share the code on jsfiddle? In the meantime, please check the following code http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/  it is a very simple example :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have timestamps ,you can't use datetime  and categories simultaneously in xAxis . If you want to use categories , user laebl formatter as I used in [This Fidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/59kgtr0q/5/)

Also categories should have string array.
If you want to use type:datetime in your xAxis , either you should get processed data from backend as

```
[timestamp,value],[timestamp,value]
```

for each series. Or if you can't get that from server do processing in javascript and make two datasets as following

```
 //code
```